# How to adjust cell size in latex? this is my code but it looks quite congested. also is there any way to wrap text in top row?

Tags: latex

```latex
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllccc}
        \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Equipment}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Mass in (kg) (wet   basis)}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Mass out (kg)}} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{}} \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{NG Preheater} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} &
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Primary   Reformer}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Secondary   Reformer} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114612.9197} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114612.9197} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{HTS}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{LTS}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{CO2 Bulk   Absorber}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{88197.06698} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{60609.14025} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{CO2 Lean   Absorber}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{60609.14025} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{48485.42083} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Methanator}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{48485.42083} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{48485.42083} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Purifier}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{46964.94183} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{46964.94183} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Syngas   Converter}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{80287.85685} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{80287.85685} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             &  &  & 
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Units involving heat transfer}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You may also want to check out the [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @VEED Can you please make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: Off-topic: avoid these dreadful latex table generators. All these unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}` only cause problems

Comment: Also, columns 4, 5 and 6 are empty and do not show!

Answer (score 1):

I commented three small portions of your code, including one redundant `\multirow`.

After that, lines 4 and 5 of my code below may help.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}    
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{table}%[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllccc}
        \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Equipment}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Mass in (kg) (wet   basis)}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Mass out (kg)}} &
        %\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{}} 
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{}} \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{NG Preheater} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} &
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Primary   Reformer}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{63027.02528} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Secondary   Reformer} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114612.9197} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114612.9197} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{HTS}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{LTS}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{114533.9399} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{CO2 Bulk   Absorber}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{88197.06698} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{60609.14025} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{CO2 Lean   Absorber}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{60609.14025} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{48485.42083} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Methanator}           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{48485.42083} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{48485.42083} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Purifier}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{46964.94183} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{46964.94183} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Syngas   Converter}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{80287.85685} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{80287.85685} &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             &  &  & 
    \end{tabular}
%\caption{Units involving heat transfer}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is what it outputs:

[image: screenshot of output table]

---

Smarter code, without the redundant `multirow` and `multicolumn`s as in the comment by SamCarter, still with the empty column number four, five and six (although I believe they are unwanted). The `caption` must be followed by a `label` to work correctly!

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{table}%[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|ccc}
  \cline{1-3}
  \textbf{Equipment} & %
  \textbf{Mass in (kg) (wet basis)} & %
  \textbf{Mass out (kg)} & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  NG Preheater       & 63027.02528 & 63027.02528 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  Primary Reformer   & 63027.02528 & 63027.02528 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  Secondary Reformer & 114612.9197 & 114612.9197 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  HTS                & 114533.9399 & 114533.9399 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  LTS                & 114533.9399 & 114533.9399 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  CO2 Bulk Absorber  & 88197.06698 & 60609.14025 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  CO2 Lean Absorber  & 60609.14025 & 48485.42083 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  Methanator         & 48485.42083 & 48485.42083 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  Purifier           & 46964.94183 & 46964.94183 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
  Syngas Converter   & 80287.85685 & 80287.85685 & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Units involving heat transfer}
\label{any}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```